# Importing text file into SAS: Date without the leading zeros

Tags: date, text, import, sas, string-length

I'm trying to import a text data file into SAS. It's like this,

```
EmployeeID    Birthday   Gender
10001    5/1/1978   Female
10005    9/16/1982   Male
...
```

Here is my code,

```
data employee;
   infile "employee2015.txt" delimiter='    ' firstobs=2;
   input employeeid birthday MMDDYY10. gender $;
run;
```

It doesn't work because the length of the date is not fixed, so the next variable Gender will be affected (something like "emale" would appear). If I change it to MMDDYY8. there will be some numbers appear in Gender's column.

I've tried importing birthday as char, it looks fine but when I try to format it to mmddyy10. there will be error reported. And I believe there must be some straight-forward ways to do that so I ask for help here...

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try the `anydtdte.` informat instead of `mmddyy10.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your delimiter specification and create an informat statement instead to read the data properly. You may need to customize the informat statement to meet your actual data needs.

```
data want;
informat employeeid $5. birthday mmddyy10. gender $8.;
format birthday date9.;
input EmployeeID $   Birthday   Gender $;
cards;
10001    5/1/1978   Female
10005    9/16/1982   Male
;
run;

proc print;run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem completely solved. However my data is from a text file. If I remove the delimiter specification the imported data would be all messed up. I think it's the informat statement that does the trick.

Comment: Possibly, but SAS uses spaces a default delimiter. If its a tab it should have been specified as '09'x instead.